# How to solve "Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Builders.TableBuilder'" while publishing to AZURE?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

I'm trying to publish a Web.API in .NEt 4.5 with EF6 to Azure.

But when I am getting the following exception when I try running my project. How could I fix that?

```
Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Builders.TableBuilder
```

Comment: did you addded the corespoting package to the project?

Comment: Which should be the corrsponding projects? I mean when I run it locally everything works fine, so I guess the project has all the packages it needs.

Comment: Try to apply the solution given on thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640904/error-running-code-first-igration-update-database

Comment: Uninstall/Re-install Entity Framework solved it for me.